# Store data for temporary in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database which contains 10000 words. now i want to pick  5 words randomly from that database and want to store them for 1 day.That means after 1 day it will pick another random 5 words from the database and show them to the user.
Now the fact is i don't understand how to store these data and pick them randomly after each fixed period of time. I thought to use database to store these random words but i think it will not be efficient,may b there is another efficient way to do that.Can anyone tell me how can i do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of using database in `Android`. But, to store record temporary you can use`SharedPreferences` like,

To Save:

```
SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "app_pref";
public static final String KEY_p_id = "KEY_test";

        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(Login_screen.KEY_test, values.get(0));
        editor.commit();
```

To Remove:

```
editor.remove("KEY_test").commit();
```

Comment: How can i check the time that whether it passes 1 day or not ??  @android_beginner

Answer (score 1):

You could use the month/day/year portion of the current timestamp to seed your random number generator. That way you don't need to temporarily store your random values as they will always be the same for a given day.

Answer (score 0):

When randomly selected the words, you should store a timestamp. So the next time the random words are requested, you simply compare the timestamp with the current time to see if you need to pick up another 5 random words.

You can use `SharedPreferences` as an alternative storage option.